# How do I make dynamically inserted html objects clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I have:

```
function createLink(text, parentElement) {
    var a = document.createElement('p');
    $( parentElement ).on( 'click', 'a', function () { goMainMenuFromResults();});
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    temp1 = text.replace("/","-");
    parentElement.appendChild(a);
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    parentElement.appendChild(br);

}
```

But on clicking any element dynamically made nothing happens!

Comment: `.on( 'click', 'a',` you are setting a click event handler for any `<a>` elements in the `parentElement`, but you haven't created an `<a>` element, just a `<p>`,`<br>` and a text node

Comment: At first glance, it appears that you're trying to create an <a> element using `document.createElement('p')`, which creates a <p> element. Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
$( parentElement ).on( 'click', 'a', function () { goMainMenuFromResults();});
```

After:

```
$( parentElement ).on( 'click', 'p', function () { goMainMenuFromResults();});
```

Comment: Just remove the quotes from 'a' and it will work mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass object and it should not be in quotes.
Use this:

```
 $( parentElement ).on( 'click', a, function () { goMainMenuFromResults();});
```

And here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/toa0sqfo/

What you were doing, was asking the dom to attach event handler to an "Anchor" object, which is wrong. Patrick has revealed this already in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the `'a'` of the `$( parentElement ).on( 'click', 'a', function () { goMainMenuFromResults();});`that's will be ok;